# Philosophy of anti-thinking: What does it feel like to consciously not think about X?

Tags: consciousness, emotions, neurophilosophy

Take apples as an example:
When we think of apples, we think of e.g. a round shaped object that is red and is juicy.

But when we are not thinking about apples, we are either not aware we are unconsciously thinking about apples, or apples never get called up consciously (or for the materialists, there are no neutral states that corresponds to the state of thinking about apples)

Whenever we try to consciously not thinking about apples, we often start with thinking what attributes an apple have and avoiding those attributes, thus in the process we end up conceiving the concept of an apple anyway (this is what the meme known as The Game based on)

So is it possible to consciously not thinking about apples, and if so, what does that mental or emotional state felt like. Any literature topic that investigate these kinds of antithinking?

Comment: "Tibetan book of the Dead", Nagarjuna's metaphysics, pyrhonist metaphysics, the trillema fallacies (munchauseen, agrippa, Frie), Lucretius "the nature of things", these are a few places to start.

Comment: Trying to not think about X specifically is self-defeating, since one has to focus on X to exclude it. But clearing your mind generally is a part of [Oriental meditation techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhist_meditation).

Comment: there's a very famous saying by dogen, the soto (japanese meditation) zen monk, "how do you think of not thinking? without thinking". it's unclear -- in the western commentaries -- whether it's meant like koan practice, or is just basic buddhist meditation. i have practiced it, though never under a **soto** master, and for me it's a means primarily to listen and stay alert to sitting (though the fukanzazengi also says it has nothing to do with [sitting](https://sanfranciscozencenter.blob.core.windows.net/assets/21_Fukanzazengi.pdf)

Comment: you might want to look into the tao, also.

Comment: Some paradoxes are contradictory self-references (for example: "This sentence is false"). This notion falls into such category. Nothing new here.

Comment: A sensory variant of this is what you experience when you concentrate on what you see in front of you when you're in a dark room with your eyes closed (blackness) vs. what you experience when you try to concentrate on what's past the edge of your field of vision--in this case you don't have to consciously try to avoid thinking about anything, you can try but it's just an absence of sensation. And it's also interesting how your visual perception sort of fades into absence at the edges rather there being any abrupt boundary between "vaguely perceiving something" and "not perceiving".

Comment: "what does it feel like" is never a philosophical question. Also how to change what we think about seems like a psychology question as well.

Answer (score 0):

To use the apples example: Not thinking about apples feels precisely like the following: For all x not being thought about, not thinking about apples feels precisely like not thinking x.

That's not really an answer, but it's a helpful reminder that any answer can answer the entire set of examples.

The example of "consciously not thinking about apples" is ambiguous: do you mean consciously thinking of something that isn't an apple? I presume you don't, but that settles the answer of what it feels like to not think about apples: either (A) not being conscious, or (B) Whatever it feels like to you now, not thinking of whatever it is you're not thinking of.

A more interesting interpretation is whether we can consciously think the thought "Apples are something I'm not thinking of" and have that belief be true. The question then really depends; could someone have that thought, but not have any phenomenal experience of apples? In general, i'd say no, but it's plausible there's exceptions. Then we boil it down to: is framing apples in your mind without having a mental experience of thinking about them, still thinking about them? I don't know; this isn't particularly of interest to me. But i'd hazard a guess that the answer to the question, framed that way, is the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

According to Parmenides 'not thinking' is not possible. That is thinking always has a referent. So to not think about an apple means that you are thinking of something else, like a pear.

Comment: Some sources and elaboration could make this a very good answer. [The Stanford Encyclopedia](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/parmenides/) has a relevant quote from Bertrand Russel about Parmenides, but a quote directly from Parmenides would be ideal.